# Disable Auto Updates for specific app on Fire TV

Tags: applications, application-autoupdate, amazon-fire-tv

Is there a way to disable automatic updates for a specific app on a Fire TV device without disabling auto-update for all apps?

I have a specific app that I sideloaded an old version (but is also on the app store). I'm worried that if I have auto-update on it will update to the app store version. Optimally I'd like auto-updates on for all apps except for the one I sideloaded. Thanks!

Comment: Usually, this setting is on the App Store itself, like Google Play Store has "Enable auto update" setting on per-app entry.

Comment: I don't think such a setting exists for the Fire TV Store.